# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Alright, I completely give up, I am on it for the last 2 hours, I can't understand why it is not working.

I added :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Also :

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I added my run :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'firebase', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.configs', ])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $timeout) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    console.log('Platform ready!');

    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

And my controller :

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {    

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
        });

        var posOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };

        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };          

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);          

            $scope.map = map;   
            $ionicLoading.hide();           

        }, function(err) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
```

Whatever I do, from a ionic serve, view or build on Android, I get the same error : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined**

EDIT : Here is the head of my controller :

```
.controller('businessPageController',['$scope', '$timeout', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', '$document', '$state',   function($scope, $timeout, $firebaseArray, CONFIG, $document, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, ionicPlatform, ngCordova)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED !**

Alright, if you are a NOOB in Javascript and Angular, just like me, and you find this post, here is the solution I have just found, that is probably in every first chapter of every Javascript / Angular book :

When writing the functions of a controller, you **have to put them in order of appearance** in your controller !

So here is what I had :

```
.controller('businessPageController',['$scope', '$timeout', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', '$document', '$state',   function($scope, $timeout, $firebaseArray, CONFIG, $document, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, ionicPlatform, ngCordova)
```

And here is what **HAS TO BE** written :

```
.controller('businessPageController',['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', '$ionicLoading', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$timeout', '$firebaseArray',    'CONFIG', '$document', '$state',   function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading, $cordovaGeolocation, $timeout, $firebaseArray, CONFIG, $document, $state,   ngCordova)
```